# Origin of the name “integral” or “ring of integers”

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I gave a talk recently in which I introduced rings of integers and computed a few examples of the ring of integers in number fields. When I gave the definition of an element being “integral” over a ring, I was asked about the motivation for the name. I didn’t have an answer, and I haven’t found anything in the few number theory books I’ve looked at.

Is there a deeper reason or motivation as to why we have given these elements the name “integral”, or why, in the case of number fields, we call the integral elements the “integers” of the field?

The best I’ve thought of is that, in the case of a number field $K$, the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ has $K$ as its fraction field. So this is analogous to the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ has $\mathbb{Q}$ as its fraction field. Hence with this analogy, $\mathcal{O}_K$ are the “integers” of $K$.

Comment: It's not just that, $\mathcal{O}_K$ is far from the only ring with that property. It's because they behave like the integers in that you can talk about factorization and working mod a prime so forth. Note also that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ThePirateBay You didn't read the question. Be better.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see. Would you care to elaborate in an answer?

Comment: @NicholasCamacho. Dont really have time, sorry. I'm sure someone will answer your question.

Comment: As to why $\mathcal{O}_K$ is called the ring of integers of a number field, it's because $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$, i.e. it's the smallest subring of $K$ that behaves like $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: As you said, the main goal is to define a ring $O_K$ in a number field $K$ which plays the same role as $Z$ w.r.t. $Q$. The single property that $Frac(O_K)=K$ is not enough, because there are other subrings of $K$ which verify this property (they are called *orders*, and $O_K$ is the maximal order). Besides, any $x\in K$ must be algebraic, i.e. must be a root of a polynomial $f(X)\in K[X]$. The natural idea is then to impose the coefficients of $f$ to belong to $Z$. But this still insufficient...

Comment: ... : just think of $aX-b$, with $a, b \in Z, ab \neq 0$; then $x=b/a  \in Q$ could certainly not be considered as an integral element ! Hence the additional condition that the leading coefficient is not null, and you get the usual definition of an algebraic integer. This carries over *verbatim* to the definition of integral elements in an extension of rings, for use e.g. in algebraic geometry.